# Python logic Black Jack sim

Tags: python

I can't figure out where I did mistake but print is always Likely victories 100%

```
import random
```

Setting up deck and check scores of single game

```
def singleGame():
    cardsVal = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10] # deck of cards
    onhandScore = 17 # score on hand
    cardNumber = pickOneCard()
    newCardValue = cardsVal[cardNumber - 1]
    onhandScore = onhandScore + newCardValue
```

Check if win, lose or tie

```
if onhandScore > 21:
    result = 1
elif onhandScore == 21:
    result = 0
else:
    result = -1

return result
```

Pick one card of 13 and return its card number

```
def pickOneCard():
    return random.randint(1, 13)
```

Check for n simulations and print the results

```
def multipleGames(n):
```

To record score

```
defeat = 0;
certainVictory = 0;
likelyVictory = 0;
```

Simulating n games one by one

```
for i in range(n):
    result = singleGame()
```

Check scores and store values

```
if result == 1:
    defeat += 1
elif result == 0:
    certainVictory += 1
else:
    likelyVictory += 1
```

Calculating total percentage

```
totalPer = (defeat + certainVictory + likelyVictory)
defeatPer = float("{0:.2f}".format(defeat * 100/ totalPer))
certainVictoryPer = float("{0:.2f}".format(certainVictory * 100/ totalPer))
likelyVictoryPer = 100 - defeatPer - certainVictoryPer
```

Printing results

```
print 'Defeats: ',defeatPer,'%'
print 'Certain victories: ',certainVictoryPer,'%'
print 'Likely victories: ',likelyVictoryPer,'%'
```

Simulating code for 100,000 games

```
multipleGames(100000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your indentation for checking win, lose or tie. Your return statement should be outside the if statement like so.

```
if onhandScore > 21:
    result = 1
elif onhandScore == 21:
    result = 0
else:
    result = -1

return result
```

Because of this, an integer value is only returned when it reaches the `else` case. Otherwise the function returns `None` by default. Now when we reach here.

```
if result == 1:
    defeat += 1
elif result == 0:
    certainVictory += 1
else:
    likelyVictory += 1
```

`None` does not equal `1` or `0` so it reaches the `else`, and when it does `return -1` this also adds one for `likelyVictory`.